# Why doesn't 1-cyclopropylethyne give a positive reaction in the bromine-water unsaturation test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reactivity, hydrocarbons

1-cyclopropylethyne has a triple bond:

[image]

Hence it seems like it should yield a positive unsaturation test with bromine water. But, my book states that the opposite is true.

I guess this may be due to steric crowding on the C atom bearing the cyclopropyl ring, but I'm not sure.

What is the exact reason that 1-cyclopropylethyne does not yield a positive bromine water unsaturation test?

Comment: I'd guess that it is too insoluble in water to react with an aqueous water solution.

Comment: @MaxW I would assume that wet THF would be a fine solvent for this type of reaction...